# Can I use with() instead Load() Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
 $school=$school->teachers->load('TeacherCourses');
```

This will return all teachers with their courses in my laravel project..

can I use with() function like below?? if I cant then how ?

```
 $school=$school->teachers->with('TeacherCourses');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the correct syntax would be different. `load()` is used after you've retrieved the model from the Database, but `with()` is used prior to that.

```
$school = School::first();
$school->teachers->load('teacherCourses');
```

̶T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶,̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶`̶t̶e̶a̶c̶h̶e̶r̶s̶`̶ ̶s̶u̶g̶g̶e̶s̶t̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶C̶o̶l̶l̶e̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶`̶l̶o̶a̶d̶(̶)̶`̶ ̶m̶e̶t̶h̶o̶d̶.̶ Corrected by @patricus; `Collection`s do have a `load()` method, so `->teachers->load('teacherCourses')` will work. Alternative syntax would be:

```
$school->load('teachers.teacherCourses');
```

The more efficient way to write this is:

```
$school = School::with('teachers.teacherCourses')->first();
```

This will eager-load both the `teachers` and `teacherCourses` nested relationships, in a minimal number of database calls.

Edit

Route Model Binding will do this behind-the-scenes:

```
$school = School::findOrFail($schoolId);
```

Since it's only loading a single Model, using `load()` is perfectly acceptable. `with()` loads the relationships via a single query, for a total of 1 + (# of relationships loaded) queries (3 in your case, `school`, `teachers` and `teacherCourses`). `load()` will do the same thing, so there's no need to use `with()` over `load()` in this case.

Comment: But I have done Route model binding the function then how its work.. like i only need the data for specific school id

Comment: Probably best if you include that information in your question, since it's pretty relevant to your approach... That being said, `load()` is perfectly fine, since you're only fetching a single model. `with()` is efficient when you're loading a bunch of models, since it'll call a single query to fetch all the relationships for each loaded record, but if there's only one record, it's still a single query.

Comment: See my edit on using `load()` with nested relationships.

Comment: @TimLewis Just an FYI, the Eloquent Collection does have a `load()` method. It will load the specified relationship(s) for all the models in the Collection. Example: `$school->teachers->load('teacherCourses')` would load the `teacherCourses` relationship for all the teacher models in the `teachers` collection.

Comment: @patricus Cool! Generally, calling methods on a Collection that affect a Model instance within the Collection is a no-op, I assumed (incorrectly) that would be the same for `load()`. Answer updated, thanks!